# Where NULL IS NULL

Tags: postgresql, isnull

I'm seeing a lot of `where NULL IS NULL` type conditions in code and I'm curious about the overhead that may be involved in this.

So given `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'TERM' AND (NULL IS NULL OR anotherField = NULL)` on a table > 10+ million records.  Would there be enough concern to enforce the removal of the `NULL IS NULL` condition or the difference is negligible?

Developers are using this syntax to write generic SQL that handles optional query parameters.  Personally I feel it should be left off the query if the parameter is not provided as it seems redundant.

I've done a little bit of Googling on this and I can't seem to find the answer, maybe my search terms are off as it seems common.

Comment: what rdbms is this?

Comment: Optimizer in most RDBMSs detects and evaluates constants only once. `WHERE something = 'TERM' AND NULL IS NULL` => `WHERE something = 'TERM' AND True` => `WHERE something = 'TERM'`. I think You have no chance to detect the difference in execution time.

Comment: @DecafDb You put `AND`, not `OR`, between partial filter conditions. Is that right?

Comment: @Akina Yes sorry, I have updated the query.

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron Postgresql

Comment: It's unlikely that you have exactly this: `(NULL IS NULL OR anotherField = NULL)`. More likely you have `(parameter IS NULL OR anotherField = parameter)`, so when the parameter is NULL, the parenthesis evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before and I did a quick search to verify it. I'll tell you what I think you're looking just as a guess, from [use-the-index-luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic)

> ```
> SELECT first_name, last_name, subsidiary_id, employee_id
>   FROM employees
>   WHERE ( subsidiary_id    = :sub_id OR :sub_id IS NULL )
>     AND ( employee_id      = :emp_id OR :emp_id IS NULL )
>     AND ( UPPER(last_name) = :name   OR :name   IS NULL )
> ```
>
> The query uses named bind variables for better readability. All possible filter expressions are statically coded in the statement. Whenever a filter isn't needed, you just use `NULL` instead of a search term: it disables the condition via the `OR` logic.

So I think you're looking at is dynamically generated SQL. You have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 'TERM' AND NULL IS NULL
```

I don't think that's right, I think that's a placeholder or prepared statement that looks like this,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ($1 = 'TERM' OR $1 IS NULL);
```

And ultimately that's whole statement gets left empty so it looks like,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (null = 'TERM' OR null IS NULL);
```

That makes it so the conditional loses all selectivity and is pruned in query compilation. That's all background,

> Would there be enough concern to enforce the removal of the NULL IS NULL condition or the difference is negligible?

Yes, the `null IS NULL` gets [constant folded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) with `true` (in every database I know about), and both `false OR true` and `true OR false` gets simplified to `true`.

Comment: thanks @Evan Carrol.  Yes sorry I've updated the example.  So it's more like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'TERM' AND (NULL IS NULL OR anotherField = NULL)`.  My concern is that `AND (NULL IS NULL OR anotherField = NULL)` could be left off during the query string generation and possibly has undesired effects at reasonable scale.

Comment: Oh yeah I stay the hell away from ORMs.  I have always build the string myself and always left off anything redundant and kept queries specific and fairly atomic, which has always worked really well for me even up to quite a large scale.  But this project is full these types of generic queries which could have 4-5 optional parameters like this.  So it got me a little concerned.